# Computing some cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $D^n$ be a $n$-dimensional disk, $n>1$, and $X$ a path connected topological space.

I need to show that $H^{n+k}(D^n\times X/(\partial D^n)\times X)\cong H^{k}(X)$.

Any ideas?

I've tried the Mayer-Vietoris sequence but didn't succeed. Also, I've tried thinking about relative cohomology.

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the Mayer-Vietoris sequence but didn't succeed. Also, I've tried thinking about relative cohomology.

Comment: If you have access to "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff, they give an argument in Appendix A on starting on page 265. Specifically they show the *cohomology cross product* induces an isomorphism $H^k(X) \cong H^{k+n}(X\times \mathbb{R}^n, X\times(\mathbb{R}^{n} - 0))$, where the relative group is the same as your relative group by homotopy invariance and excision. In a broader context, this is the first step in the proof of the Thom Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: I would like there to be a more elementary argument by showing that $D^n \times X / (\partial D^n \times X)$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^n \wedge X \cong \Sigma^n X$ the $n$-fold suspension, and then the result would follow from the suspension isomorphism. However I haven't managed to work out the details so it might not be the case.

Comment: @William : it's not $S^n\wedge X$, but simply $S^n\times X$ (try to visualize it for $n= 1$ : you're taking $X\times I$ and collapsing $X\times\{0\}\cup X\times \{1\}$). The proof is purely categorical if $X$ is locally compact (it's then exponentiable, so $X\times -$ preserves colimits). I guess you can get to a proof without that hypothesis in that special case. Then it'll just be the Künneth theorem

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I'm a bit confused, since by taking the quotient by $X\times \partial D^n$ we're not collapsing the boundaries fibre-wise, we're collapsing ALL of the boundaries into a single point: isn't this the Thom space? I tried defining a map $h\colon (X\times D^n)/(X\times \partial D^n) \to X\times (D^n/\partial D^n)$ by $h([x, v]) = (x, [v])$, but if $v, v'\in \partial D^n$ then $[x,v]=[x',v']$ for all $x, x'$, and if $x\neq x'$ then $(x,[v])\neq (x',[v'])$ so $h$ is not well-defined. What have I don't wrong/what is the correct map?

Comment: @William : you're right, I spoke too quickly ! I was thinking about a coequalizer diagram, but that coequalizer diagram is not $X\times -$ some other coequalizer diagram, so my argument of colimit-preservation completely fails - and I had misvisualized the $n=1$ case. If you try to visualize it correctly, you see that for $n=1$ it seems to behave as $\Sigma X$ with the two tips connected. Maybe it's a quotient space of $S^n\wedge X$ more generally ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think I remembered how this is supposed to work: the Thom space of a trivial rank $n$ bundle over $X$ is $\Sigma^n X_+$, where "$X_+$" is $X$ union a disjoint basepoint (here our disjoint basepoint is the equivalence class of $X\times \partial D^n$) and $\Sigma^n$ is the reduced suspension. Then we can use the suspension isomorphism like $H^k(X) \cong \tilde{H}^k(X_+) \cong \tilde{H}^{n+k}(\Sigma^n X_+)$ and the last group is the same as unreduced cohomology since $n>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to consider the homeomorphic space $X\times I^n/(X \times \partial I^n)$ instead, for reasons which will become apparent. First some terminology might help.

For $(X,x_0)$ a pointed topological space, define the *reduced suspension*

$$ \Sigma X = X \times I/\sim $$

where $(x,v)\sim (x',v')$ iff either $1)$ $v = v' = 1$, $2)$ $v = v' = 0$, or $3)$ $x = x' = x_0$. You can visualize this by taking the suspension as usual and then collapsing the subspace $\{x_0\} \times I$. Note that in particular the entire subspace $X \times \partial I$ is identified with the basepoint, and this definition is equivalent to $X\times I /(X \times \partial I \cup x_0 \times I)$. It is a fact that if $X$ is "well-pointed" (i.e. the inclusion of the basepoint has the homotopy extension property) then the reduced suspension is homotopy-equivalent to the usual suspension.

Since $\Sigma X$ is still pointed by the equivalence class of $x_0$, we can iterate this process and define $\Sigma^n X = \Sigma(\Sigma^{n-1}X)$ for $n >1$. By induction you can prove the following formula:

$$ \Sigma^n X \cong X \times I^n / (X\times \partial I^n \cup x_0 \times I^n). $$

This looks very similar to our quotient $X\times I^n/(X\times \partial I^n)$ but in our case we don't identify the subspace with any point in $X$, and $X$ was never assumed to be pointed to begin with. However, if $X$ is any space (not necessarily pointed) we can form the well-pointed space $X_+ = X \sqcup \{+\}$ with disjoint basepoint "$+$", and my claim, which you should prove, is that (as long as $X$ is non-empty)
$$X\times I^n / (X \times \partial I^n) \cong \Sigma^n(X_+).$$

Since $X_+$ is well-pointed it follows that the reduced suspension is homotopy equivalent to the usual suspension, so we still have a suspension isomorphism. In particular if $k\geq 0$ and $n>0$ then

$$ H^k(X) \cong \tilde{H}^k(X_+) \cong \tilde{H}^{k+n}(\Sigma^n X_+) \cong H^{k+n}(X\times I^n/(X\times \partial I^n)) $$

(where the last group can be written unreduced because $k+n > 0$).

---

Although the argument outlined above is very geometric in nature and doesn't require a lot of algebraic machinery, I think the argument using the cohomology cross product given in "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff (found starting on page 265 in Appendix A) is very enlightening from an algebraic point of view, and feels less "tricky".

Comment: Ah, nicely done ! I have to admit my geometric intuition on $X\times I^n /(X \times \partial I^n)$ was a bit flawed, but once it's mentioned the isomorphism you point to is quite straightforward (using nothing but adjunction properties)